# Can the arguments of main's signature in C++ have the unsigned and const qualifiers?

Tags: c++, signature, program-entry-point

The standard explicitly states that `main` has two valid (i.e., guaranteed to work) signatures; namely:

```
int main();
int main(int, char*[]);
```

My question is simple, would something like the following be legal?

```
int main(const unsigned int, const char* const* argv);
```

My tests say 'yes', but I'm unsure of the answer because am I not overloading `main` by changing `int` to `unsigned int` as well as the non top-level `const`-ness of argv? If I am, then that's clearly prohibited.

So, are these modifications guaranteed to work on a standards conforming compiler?

Comment: why would you want to do something like that? Just write standard-conforming code

Comment: Glen, I _want_ to write conforming code. That's why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: Then declare `int main(int, char **)` and be on your way.

Comment: Again, I was hoping that someone could quote the standard or something and show me that this is illegal. I realize that main's signature is ancient and it's been done this way forever, but I couldn't care less what people are used to. I was hoping for a concrete answer. =\

Comment: @bh9042, but you know what the conforming code is, you posted it yourself.  As the second piece of code you posted isn't either of the 2 conforming signatures for main then it's obviously not conforming to the standard.  And just because most compilers let you away with the non-conforming code now, it doesn't mean that they'll let you do it in the next version

Comment: More generic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The C++98 standard says in section 3.6.1 paragraph 2

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both the following definitions of `main`: `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

So it's not mandated by the standard that the env accepting `main` is acceptable but it is permissible.

---

Because this is referred to often, here is the previous paragraph exempting freestanding environments from anything but documenting their behavior:

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. It is
>   implementation defined
>   whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function. [Note: in a freestanding environment, startup
>   and termination is implementation defined;
>   startup
>   contains the execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static storage duration; termination
>   contains the execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration. ]

Comment: Ah, I missed the "type" part when I read it.

Answer (score 20):

You must use one of the standard-conformant signatures to be standard-conformant.

I fully understand why you want to do it your way. The best way is to write your own function **myMain()** or whatever with the signature you want and call it from main(), including the required casts.

Comment: +1 for providing a useful answer instead of everyone else's "I don't see why you'd do this."

Answer (score 2):

The `argv` pointers shouldn't be `const char* const` because the program is allowed to change the buffers.

Comment: **Only** the strings, not the pointers to the strings.

Comment: That's the point. I don't want to change anything!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from reading the standard, you're being non-standards-compliant. But I can't imagine a compiler that wouldn't let you do this. As in, it'd take more work from the compiler to specifically ban an edge case that is mostly harmless and very obscure.

Comment: Amen. your code MAY have issues compiling on a hypothetical compiler that 100% follows the standard. But most compilers do not, and this edge case is probably one of those where they allow what is technically an illegal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work if the compiler uses name mangling for `main`. It's a C++ function after all. Hence, the linker will be looking for two particular "manglings". Your definition would have another mangled name.

Note that `main` is special (doesn't overload, not callable) and might not require name mangling at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might be illegal by the standard, but most runtimes don't really care. They'll just push an integer for `argc` and a pointer for `argv`, call your `main`, and hope you parse them right.  So, in your purview, "guaranteed to work" is debatable as the loader really doesn't care what you've declared the arguments as.

If it builds, `main` will get called.  How you parse the arguments is up to you.  I should clarify that this is highly platform-specific, as is nearly this entire question.

That said, **why?**

Comment: 1. argc is guaranteed to be non-negative, I want to see an unsigned somewhere in there... ;)    2. I want the extra safety net that const provides against stupid mistakes. Like I responded to jeffamaphone, even though I'm allowed to change argv, I don't want or need to.

Comment: `main` predates C++, and even the time of `unsigned`. Regardless of what you want, `main` has been declared this way for a long, long time. You really need the compiler to protect you from modifying `argv`? If you don't have that `const` there are you accidentally going to replace all the '-' with '/' in your `argv` strings? You're not selling me on why this is needed.

Comment: I think it's a valid point that allowing programmers to specify assumptions and constraints through modifiers like `unsigned` and `const` should be allowed anywhere. If it's good for user-defined functions, I don't see why it wouldn't be good for `main()` too.

Comment: afaics, there is nothing platform specific in this question.

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3

Section 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.