# How many arguments does main() have in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

What numbers of arguments are used for `main`? What variants of `main` definition is possible?

Comment: Right there in the "Related" links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621574/mains-signature-in-c Also, you tagging is inconsistent with your title.

Comment: added `c++` tag for consistency with title

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**C++ Standard: ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621574/mains-signature-in-c/1621664#1621664))**

The C++98 standard says in section 3.6.1.2

> It shall have a return type of type
>   int, but otherwise its type is
>   implementation-defined. All
>   implementations shall allow both the
>   following definitions of main: int
>   main() and int main(int argc, char*
>   argv[])

**Commonly there are 3 sets of parameters:**

- no parameters / `void`
- `int argc, char ** argv`
- `int argc, char ** argv, char ** env`

Where `argc` is the number of command lines, `argv` are the actual command lines, and `env` are the environment variables.

**Windows:**

For a windows application you have an entry point of WinMain with a different signature instead of main.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  __in  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  __in  int nCmdShow
);
```

**OS X: ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_(programming)))**

Mac OS X and Darwin have a fourth parameter containing arbitrary OS-supplied information, such as the path to the executing binary:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple)
```

Comment: and what about auxv in linux?

Comment: @osgx : I'm not sure if others are possible but the 3 mentioned commonly above are supported by g++

Comment: I have never understood the requirement that `main` return `int`.  `main` is the only function explicitly allowed to have an implicit return value.  Why go out of your way to allow `main` to pretend to be `void`, rather than simply allowing it to be `void` to begin with?

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Sounds like a great question for stackoverflow.com :)