# What happens when you don't follow the practice of argv and argc

Tags: c++, c, command-line, command-line-arguments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [main(int argc, char *argv[])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898021/mainint-argc-char-argv)
>   [Main's Signature in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621574/mains-signature-in-c)

If i write:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

i get proper commandline input.
What would happen if i wrote say,

```
int main(int foo, double fooDouble, fooType FooVar)
```

Is this OS-dependent or does it depend on the compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [main(int argc, char *argv\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898021/mainint-argc-char-argv) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734111/what-are-the-arguments-to-main-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Main's Signature in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621574/mains-signature-in-c) and [How many arguments does main() have in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525183/how-many-arguments-does-main-have-in-c-c)

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282151/can-we-overload-main-function-in-c

Comment: @Marcelo: "Why don't you try it?" is never a valid answer for undefined behavior, and in fact it's actively harmful advice if left unqualified. -1 to comment if I could...

Comment: @R: I find such experimentation quite enlightening, actually: http://codepad.org/e6RZyBKQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that it does compile, it will still only be called with the argc and argv arguments.

So your fooDouble will get the pointer value of argv, and FooVar will get whatever value is in that register/stack space used for that argument position (which may not have been initialized by the callee, so it may hold any undefined value).

Comment: Although you can call main() from anywhere within your program, just like any other function, passing whatever the prototype allows.

Comment: @cdarke: No you can not, the standard says you shall not call `main`.

Comment: Hmm, g++ seems to compile and run a program with a call to main(int, char **) without any errors... is that a bug in g++?

Comment: @Xeo, I'd say you still can, even if it is to be avoided. As you say _"you shall not"_, doesn't mean you can't.

Answer (score 5):

This code doesn't even have to compile. If it does, undefined behaviour may occur.

Comment: ooh, shiny undefined behavior ;)

Comment: It's true that `undefined behaviour may occur`; however, the standard does allow alternative platform-dependant signatures in addition to the two standard onse.

Comment: Doesn't QT have a different main() signature?

Comment: @0A0D: No, it doesn't really. I have the regular one it most of my apps. However, it defines a static library (qmain.lib on windows) which normalizes things (I think it's a workaround for the windows-specific WinMain().)

Answer (score 5):

The effect of adding a third (or fourth, or fifth...) argument to `main` indeed depends on the operating system. For instance, on Windows (and I believe on Unix as well) you can have a third argument which grants access to the environment variables:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv, char **env )
```

Answer (score 2):

The C standard (BS ISO/IEC 9899:1999) gives two alternatives for main:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

It also allows equivalents, so an argv of  char ** argv for example.  Additional arguments are "neither blessed nor forbidden by the Standard".  Such addtions will be compiler and runtime (not operating system) specific.

The arguments are passed by the C runtime, which calls main().  Passing any other type would be problematic on general environments like Windows and UNIX, so quite how you would expect to pass a double or fooType is beyond me.

Invoking a program from either a command-line or using interfaces like execve (UNIX) or CreateProcess (Win32) involves passing zero delimited strings.  In theory you could hack it to pass a binary value and then cast it in main, provided it does not contain a '\0' anywhere except at the end, which would be challenging.

EDIT:  it occurs to me that you can call main() from within your program - the well known obvuscated C code "The twelve days of Christmas" does this.  In this case there is no reason why you can pass anything the prototype allows.