# Syntax understanding issue

Tags: c++, c++11

Please help me to understand the line in main function. What does that means

```
#include<iostream>

struct ABC
    {
      private:
       int A,
       float B;

      public :
       ABC() {};
       ~ABC(){};

    };

    int main()
    {
       ABC A={};     // What does this statement means?
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is not valid C++; `main` must have return type `int` in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB actually most compiler will accept that anyway, not important for this question

Comment: I need to know ,what ABC A={} mean?

Comment: Consult your book. If it doesn't cover it, get a better book.

Comment: i understand that A is  the object for ABC but why  this  ={};, I didn't understand this assignment part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954208/when-initializing-a-struct-with-syntax-whats-happening-under-the-hood

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When initializing a struct with ={} syntax, what's happening under the hood?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954208/when-initializing-a-struct-with-syntax-whats-happening-under-the-hood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABC A={};
```

This is called [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) since c++11. In this particular case it's the same as calling: `ABC A;` or `ABC A{}` or `ABC A()` etc. All it does is initializes an object calling a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`ABC A={}` is the same as invoking constructor with no parameter. In your case it is `ABC A = ABC()`;

Lets consider this class (public constructors with 0/1/2 params)

```
class Hello {
private:
  int x;
  float y;
public:
  Hello() {}
  Hello(int _x) : x(_x) {}
  Hello(int _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};
```

`Hello h = {}` == `Hello h = Hello()` == just `Hello h`

`Hello h = {1}` == `Hello h = Hello(1)` == `Hello h; h.x = 1;`

`Hello h = {1, 2}` == `Hello h = Hello(1, 2)` == `Hello h; h.x = 1; h.y = 2;`

Comment: if ABC A={} and ABC A both are same then why do we write ABC A ={} ? What is the point of using it?

Comment: `ABC A={1, 2}` is not the same as `ABC A; A.A = 1; A.B = 2;`. If you have no constructor accepting them, it won't compile! it's the same as `ABC A(1,2)` (also applies to {1} version)

Comment: @pergy You sure? struct S {
  int x;
  float y;
};

S a = {1, 2}; works for G++ 6.3.0

Comment: @JohnLondon I was talking about this exact case: private members, only default constructor

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the members are under`private, my bad. Tweak my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `ABC A={};` will call default constructor, but... if your class didn't have default constructor (provided by you) `= {}` initialization would do "a magic" - it would initialize all struct/class members with "zero/default values", i.e.: 0 for numeric types, 0.0 for floating point types, nullptr for pointers... which is much more then default default constructor does.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it has no difference irrespective of {};

But if it was like C style structure like below, then `ABC A={};` will reset its members A and B to zero.

```
struct ABC
{
    int A;
    float B;
};
```