# How many parameters can be passed to main()

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a limit for the number of parameters main can have?

Here is a sample code which runs *perfectly* … and I am not aware if it is allowed.

```
int main( char* argv[], int argc, int arv, bool test)
{
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
}
```

Output:
Hello

I am using

- gcc-4.1.2_20070115-0.32.53
- gcc-c++-4.1.2_20070115-0.32.53
- libgcc-4.1.2_20070115-0.32.53
- gcc-objc-4.1.2_20070115-0.32.53

Comment: I hardly believe there is a limit.

Comment: That is a really old verison of `gcc`, `4.8.2` provides warnings for this code.

Comment: upgeade your gcc.mine 4.4.7 gives warning

Comment: I Tried with a different version  of gcc libgcc46-4.6.1_20110701-0.13.9
it says:
test.cpp:4: error: 'int main(int, char**, char**, char**)' takes only zero or two arguments..  
seems latest versions are checking this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard [does not explicitly forbid these signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621574/1968), but it does not require them to work either. All it says is that the two following signatures must work on any compiler:

- `int main()`
- `int main(int, char**)`

And that the return type must be `int`.

Comment: That is wrong. Please look at freestanding implementations.

Comment: @Deduplicator How can it be wrong when it comes directly from the standard? Freestanding implementations have their own little niche, but people (and the standard, unless noted otherwise) talk about hosted implementations. My answer simply doesn’t apply to freestanding implementations, which don’t have a defined startup sequence at all.

Comment: Just say it only applies to hosted implementations/not to freestanding implementations, and it's ok. Yes, people mostly ask about hosted, but they still also programm the bare metal.