# Turbo C++ and Code blocks

Tags: c++, namespaces, codeblocks, program-entry-point, turbo-c++

Why should I use namespaces and int main in Code blocks while there are no namespaces in turbo c++ and I can use void main without returning any value as I learnt in schools. Is the compiler different, Is the C++ version different?

Comment: Turbo c++ is very old and very far from being standard c++. void main() is not standard c++.

Comment: Why are you using turbo c++ in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you worked on a very old version of compiler that doesn't implement the `C++` specifications completely or in other words it is not conformant to `C++`. An old version written during dos era may allow you to do many nasty/non-standard things.

In `C++` entire C++ standard library is defined within `namespace std`. You must use `using` and/or fully qualified name (with scope resolution) to access these.

`main` in C++ must return an `int` with either of the 2 signatures

```
int main();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

In short for your use cases `turbo C++` is doing wrong while `Codeblocks` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Turbo C++ is a *compiler* bundled with an IDE targetting MS-Windows. Code Block is an *IDE* supporting several compilers and platforms. That is the main difference between these two tools, so you are not comparing exactly the same things.

Secondly, `int` [is the standard return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621664/1769720) for `main`, which is also standard by convention in C and C++ for program source code entry points <sup>(1)</sup>. C++ compilers operating in standard mode expect programs to be written that way,  so your programs should conform these expectations, if you want to use conforming C++ compilers, which are what Code Block is supporting by default. However, I'm pretty sure that you code configure Code Block to use a specific compiler in a non compliant mode (or simply a non compliant compiler), since it is a flexible IDE; you might well be able to set it up to use Turbo C++, and thus make it compile non ANSI C++. That said, I don't think that Turbo C++ does not support ANSI C++.

Thirdly, Namespaces are a feature of C++, that you have to use if you want to use the standard C++ library, but nothing forces you to otherwise.

---

<sup>(1) the name is a convention, but the function itself is obviously necessary.</sup>