# Pointers predict the output

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void){
    int mat [5][5],i,j;
    int *p;            
    p = &mat [0][0];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            mat[i][j] = i+j;
    printf ("%d\t", sizeof(mat));   i=4;j=5;
    printf( "%d", *(p+i+j));
}
```

Can somebody help me with the output of this snippet . I get it the sizeof(mat) will print 50 . But help me with second printfc

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking what the output is? Why don't you just run it?

Comment: Also, the result of `sizeof(mat)` is platform specific.

Comment: Also, `void main (void){//...}` is not valid C++, so your code has undefined behaviour. See [Main's Signature in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1621574/1227469)

Comment: Does not looks much at all like C++ for the rest of it, either.

Comment: On [ideone](http://ideone.com/AVICGW) the output is 100 and 5 respectively (after fixing the code to make it compile).

Comment: `%d` is not suited for printing `size_t` (which is the result of the `sizeof` operator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(p+i+j)` will print the value stored at the address `p + i*sizeof(int) + j*sizeof(j)`

As array are stored in a linear way in the stack and `i equals 4` and `j equals 5` this will show the value of the 9th int of the array hence `mat[1][4]` which is equal to `5`

Also for the result of `sizeof(mat)`, it will be `5*5*sizeof(int)`. I assume here your int are stored on two bytes because you said it would print 50 but it totally depends on your computer. It is more usually 4 bytes long on todays computer so it could also print `100`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this second statement to:

```
printf("%d",*(p)+i+j );
```

I'm guessing you mean to print the sum of the value pointed at by `p` and the values stored in `i` and `j`