# In command line arguments why can't we use string *arr instead of char **arr

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, command-line-arguments

Why does this work

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       
        cout << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

but not this

```
int main(int argc, string *argv)
{       
        cout << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

isn't a string just a `char*`? Why can we use the first but not the latter? What is the difference between `char**` and `string*`

Comment: There is no such thing as a string in c++. String from the standard library string.h is a helper library to make dealing with a sequence of chars more easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the arguments of main's signature in C++ have the unsigned and const qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621574/can-the-arguments-of-mains-signature-in-c-have-the-unsigned-and-const-qualifi)

Comment: @NullPointer there is a standard library type called string in C++. There is nothing against an implementation allowing `int main(int argc, std::string *argv)` in the standard

Comment: @NullPointer `std::string` is defined in `<string>`, `<string.h>` is a C header (deprecated, but usable in C++) and contains helper functions for dealing with `char*`, like `strcmp` and `strlen`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen which is more or less what I said?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes there is because std::string is defined as ```typedef basic_string<char> string;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In command line arguments why can't we use `string *arr` instead of `char **arr`

You could if your compiler supports such parameters for `main`.

But the language standard doesn't require supporting such parameters, and I know of no compiler that does. So, you cannot use that because your compiler doesn't support it.

> What is the difference between `char**` and `string*`

`char**` is a pointer to `char*`. `char*` is a pointer to `char`. `char` is a funcamental type, an integer type and a character type which represents an encoded narrow character.

`string*` is a pointer to `string`. There is no such thing as `string` in the global namespace at all. There is `std::string` which is not a pointer, nor any fundamental type but a class type instead. It is defined in the header `<string>` of the standard library.

> isn't a `string` just a `char*`?

No, it is not. See above.